# Use state in Auth0 rule

Tags: auth0

I’d like to pass a custom identifier into the Auth0 authorize endpoint. The value is a guid identifying the user in our database.

I’m passing it in the state parameter of the Auth0.js authorize function.

```
    this.auth0.authorize({
        initial_screen: 'signUp',
        lead_guid: leadGuid,
        state: leadGuid
    });
```

I can see the value of `state` in the rule but it’s encoded. The documentation suggests it’s base64 but it doesn’t decode.

Before the rule, in the hosted login page, if I grab the config, I get these values:

```
  "extraParams": {
    "initial_screen": "signUp",
    "lead_guid": "33071cf4-17c4-44fe-b573-fc86dfa7e413",
    "state": "ll8tw5lkrSELOf1cnTygwBlewWrRK_Zo"
  },
  "internalOptions": {
    "initial_screen": "signUp",
    "lead_guid": "33071cf4-17c4-44fe-b573-fc86dfa7e413",
    "state": "ll8tw5lkrSELOf1cnTygwBlewWrRK_Zo",
  },
```

The `lead_guid` is coming through to `extraParams` and `internalOptions` but the state value is not being set.

If I set the value in the object that gets passed to Lock as the Auth params:

```
if (leadGuid) {
  config.extraParams.state = leadGuid;
  config.internalOptions.state = leadGuid;
}

var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
  auth: {
    redirectUrl: config.callbackURL,
    responseType: (config.internalOptions || {}).response_type ||
      config.callbackOnLocationHash ? 'token' : 'code',
    params: config.internalOptions
  },
```

When I attempt to sign up, I get this error:

> You may have pressed the back button, refreshed during login, opened
>   too many login dialogs, or there is some issue with cookies, since we
>   couldn't find your session. Try logging in again from the application
>   and if the problem persists please contact the administrator.

If I initialize auto0.WebAuth with a custom state:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: environment.auth0.clientId,
    domain: environment.auth0.domain,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: environment.auth0.audience,
    redirectUri: environment.auth0.interactiveRedirectUri,
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    state: 'anthony'
});
```

Then get the AuthResult state, I can see my custom value. The value logged by the rule seems to be the internal Auth0 state.

Is it possible for an Auth0 rule to get the value of state in plaintext so that it can be passed to a webhook?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code from your rule into the question?

Answer (score 4):

Changed the call to

```
this.auth0.authorize({
    initial_screen: 'signUp',
    lead_guid: leadGuid,
});
```

The `lead_guid` is available in the Auth0 rule using `context.request.query.lead_guid`